# Having trouble developing a KNeighboursClassifier analysis in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to produce a routine using KNeighboursClassifier in Python in Jupyter. My goal is to group the diversity values into 4 types of water masses, but when I test my code, ''Dead Kernel'' appears on my Jupyter page.

I want to produce a figure similar to this:

[image: Image showing classification]

only adapting it to my data. That's the code I'm working on:

````
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, BoundaryNorm
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from sklearn import neighbors, datasets
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

index = pd.read_excel('diverty_index.xlsx') #This is my data set

X = index[['Shannon', 'Depth']]  
y = index['Water_mass']

# default is 75% / 25% train-test split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

def plot_water_knn(X, y, n_neighbors, weights):
    X_mat = X[['Shannon', 'Depth']].values #Shannon is a diversity index
    y_mat = y.values
# Create color maps
    cmap_light = ListedColormap(['#FFAAAA', '#AAFFAA', '#AAAAFF','#AFAFAF'])
    cmap_bold  = ListedColormap(['#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF','#AFAFAF'])
    clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors, weights=weights)
    clf.fit(X_mat, y_mat)
# Plot the decision boundary by assigning a color in the color map
    # to each mesh point.

    mesh_step_size = .01  # step size in the mesh
    plot_symbol_size = 50

    x_min, x_max = X_mat[:, 0].min() - 1, X_mat[:, 0].max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = X_mat[:, 1].min() - 1, X_mat[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, mesh_step_size),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, mesh_step_size))
    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
# Put the result into a color plot
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    plt.figure()
    plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cmap_light)
# Plot training points
    plt.scatter(X_mat[:, 0], X_mat[:, 1], s=plot_symbol_size, c=y, cmap=cmap_bold, edgecolor = 'black')
    plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
    plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
    patch0 = mpatches.Patch(color='#FF0000', label='AASW')
    patch1 = mpatches.Patch(color='#00FF00', label='CDW')
    patch2 = mpatches.Patch(color='#0000FF', label='MWDW')
    patch3 = mpatches.Patch(color='#AFAFAF', label='AABW')
    plt.legend(handles=[patch0, patch1, patch2, patch3])
plt.xlabel('Shannon H')
plt.ylabel('Profundidade(m)')
plt.show()
plot_water_knn(X_train, y_train, 5, 'uniform')```
````

Comment: Have you tried running your code line by line either outside of the function or with a dubugger to step through it? At what step does it kill the kernel? What are the dimensions of your data at the step(s) before the error occurs? Can you include the full traceback of the error, if any is presented?

Comment: No, I didn't try running my code line by line. And no error appears, the  kernel simply stops running and I have to restart it. But I'll try use a debugger. Thank you for answer me!!!

Comment: Apologies for being unclear; that was more of a rhetorical question to suggest that you _do_ run through your code checking input, output, and dimensionality at each step to determine exactly where your code becomes too much for the jupyter kernel. In my experience a dead kernel either means you've used too much memory/processor for the system to handle, or there's a problem with your jupyter install

Comment: One thing at a time. First you need to sort out the **Dead kernel** issue so you can actually run some code. Then focus on the classification without worrying about the plotting (don't mix model fitting and plotting, it will drive you crazy). Once that's sorted, you can deal with the plotting. If you've never used a debugger, forget that. What you are trying to do is not too hard, it's definitely possible and not too much code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the dead kernel issue is a result of using a fine mesh (`mesh_step_size`) on a large feature space. Standardizing your data will help, and should improve the model. If it doesn't, your entire dataset might be too large for your machine.

But the first-order problem is that this code is a bit jumbled up, mixing modeling and plotting in a ort of half-written function. Let's simplify everything and start with the classifier. Forget the plotting for now.

#### Making a classifier

I refactored a bit, using conventional names for things. Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_excel('diverty_index.xlsx')

X = df[['Shannon', 'Depth']]  
y = df['Water_mass']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)
```

Note here that it's important that your samples are not in 'clumps', e.g. location A with 5 measurements at various depths, then location B with 4 measurements at different depths, etc. If they are 'clumped' like this, you can't just split randomly with `train_test_split`; instead you need to split the clumps (e.g. the locations).

Now you need to scale your data. This classifier depends on distances, and distances don't mean much if your features are different scales. So do this:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)  # Do not fit scaler to Test.
```

Now you can fit the classifier:

```py
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, weights='uniform')
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = knn.predict(y_test)
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred)
```

How does this look? What's the weighted F1 score? Does it improve if you change the value of `n_neighbors`? How good can you make this model? (Strictly speaking you should have another blind dataset to test all this, but that's a detail.)

If you got this far with an intact kernel, then you can feel good about having a somewhat useful KNN model, and you can move on to the data viz.

#### Decision region visualization

I suspect that this line was killing your kernel: `mesh_step_size = .01`, because if the features of `X` have a large range (e.g. 0 to 10,000), the mesh will be gigantic and eat your memory, crashing the kernel. But now that we've standardized the data, things are more predictable because most values will be in the range -3 to +3.

This minimalist approach adapted from [this famous plot](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html) should produce *something*:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot the validation data.
ax.scatter(X_test[:, 0], X_test[:, 1], c=y_test)

# Set up the grid parameters.
h = .02
x_min, x_max = X_train[:, 0].min() - .5, X_train[:, 0].max() + .5
y_min, y_max = X_train[:, 1].min() - .5, X_train[:, 1].max() + .5

# Make the grid.
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))

# Predict on the grid.
Z = knn.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
    
# Put the result into a color plot.
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
im = ax.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, alpha=0.2, zorder=1, shading='auto')
```

If this produces something at least, then you're off to the races. I'm sure you can add a title, axis annotation, etc, and make it pretty. Good luck.